# bibb washer metallic coating

Tags: plumbing

What is this coating? Do I remove it before installing?

[image]

EDIT

The one on the forceps is taken from the same batch of new, old stock of Danco cross reference 4L-2H replacement parts.

Comment: Interesting workbench you've got there. :) That _appears_ to be a washer, but it looks like it's chrome plated and that the plating is flaking off. Is this a new faucet? Is the piece on the forceps a match for the one under the screw in the stem behind it (just from the other stem)? Is this a brand new faucet? Please [edit] more details into your question!

Comment: @FreeMan see edit

Comment: I have seen graphite washers that appear shiny . not sure what they are made of, but graphite is there to reduce friction.